# a 'for each' statement cannot operate on an expression of type "std::vector<Vertex *, std::allocator<Vertex *>>"

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, graph

I am trying to make graph implementation in C++ using adjacency list representation. I am little new to "vectors" in c++. I am getting this error

```
class Vertex
{
    private:

    public:
    int node_id;
    string value;
    vector< std::pair<Vertex* , int> > adj_list;

    Vertex(int node_id, string value = "" )
    {
        this->node_id=node_id;
        this->value=value;
    }
};
```

next, I am making a vector of "vertices" in the following class. In for each loop, this error occurs.
"IntelliSense: a 'for each' statement cannot operate on an expression of type "std::vector<Vertex *, std::allocator<Vertex *>>"

```
class graph
{
    private:

public:

    std::vector< Vertex* > vertex_list;

    void add_node(int node_id, string value)
    {
        for each (auto var in vertex_list)      //error here in the initialization of for each
        {
            if (var->node_id==node_id)
            {
                 throw runtime_error("This node id exist already! put another id");
            }
        }
        vertex_list.push_back(new Vertex(node_id, value));
    }
}
```

I have followed a tutorial. The guy in the tutorial had same code but didn't got error. I am not sure how to resolve this intelligence issue.

Comment: `for each (auto var in vertex_list)` is not standard C++ syntax. Use a standard range based for loop instead: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for or use a standard algorithm.

Comment: This is the problem with following random tutorials. They rarely tell you when they are using an extension https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/for-each-in?view=vs-2019 - Get a good book on C++ instead, and work through that  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: C++ doesn't have `for each`.

Comment: really c++ doesn't have for each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this [ranged-for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) (untested code)

```
    for  (auto& var : vertex_list) {
        if (var->node_id==node_id) {
             throw runtime_error("This node id exist already! put another id");
        }
    }
```